Combine more than one Unicode characters to form another new character like Glyph or Conjunct in Android Studio
I am trying to create a keyboard in my native language where some characters are formed by combination of other characters.  Here is the code snippet that I have tried
<Key
        android:codes="0x91C,0x094D,0x091E"
        android:keyLabel="ज्ञ" />
    <Key
        android:codes="0x915,0x094D,0x937"
        android:keyLabel="क्ष" />
    <Key
        android:codes="0x936,0x094D,0x930"
        android:keyLabel="श्र" />

In the first example 0x91C = ज,0x094D = ् ,0x091E = ञ;  I tried with + between Unicode's, and without having any as well.  Is there any correct syntax or code I need to update here.

"It is in UTF8 format." No. 0x09 and 0x1C are some ASCII control characters.

Horizontal tab and File Separator to be exact.

I have to confess I don't fully understand android:codes but every example I've seen uses decimal numbering. Not sure it has anything at all to do with Unicode - probably not

in Java it would be "\u091C\u094D\u091E" (no idea what is meant by "in UTF8 format" - the posted unicode points need 3 bytes in UTF-8 each)

(UTF-8: 0xE0 0xA4 0x9C 0xE0 0xA5 0x8D 0xE0 0xA4 0x9E)

I tried \u091C\u094D\u091E as well, but it is not typing the character when text input.  The character label is shown on the key but not inputting that character.

Probably you mean Unicode codepoints, which it is not UTF-8. UTF8 encode them into bytes. See https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode16.0.0/core-spec/chapter-12/ for how to combine character works in Unicode -- PS: the link is a beta version of Unicode, but the first with html pages (and so there may be a lot of visualisation bugs)

Yes, its Indian script and in the link Fig.12.8 it explain how the conjuncts are formed.  In the above code it is not the problem with Unicode / codepoints.  But it is about syntax in Android / Java.

I got the solution below.

Perhaps android:code means hardware-generated keycode

Assign a code point, example - android:codes="116" and define a method in InputMethodService file
public class IndicKeyboardService extends InputMethodService implements KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener {

@Override
public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
    InputConnection inputConnection = getCurrentInputConnection();
    if (inputConnection != null) {
        switch (primaryCode) {
            case 116: // Example code, match your actual key code
                inputConnection.commitText("\u0924\u094D\u0930", 1);
                break;
            // Handle other keys...
            default:
                inputConnection.commitText(String.valueOf((char) primaryCode), 1);
                break;
        }
    }
}

This way you can combine code points to form glyphs / conjuncts.
